# XmlHttpRequest responseText empty, responseXML undefined on rapid fire ajax calls in IE

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have an application that is making many ajax calls in rapid fire succession and a new problem has appeared in IE 11 (which shows as 'edge' in the developer console under the emulation -> document mode), as well as in Microsoft Edge on a Windows 10 machine.  My initial ajax calls successfully return as expected, but after those return I attempt to make around 15 to 20 further ajax calls in succession, some of which inconsistently return with an empty string for responseText and null responseXml set for the XmlHttpRequest object.Looking at the net panel I'll see that the call returned a status 200, but the response body shows "No data to view."  The response headers show no contentLength, and no contentType specified.  The content expected is xml.  If I switch the emulator to IE 9, it seems to work more consistently, but periodically will also show the same problem.

Issues I've found on other similar posts that I've already checked:

- readyState is 4
- status is 200, statusText = "OK"
- not a same origin issue, the request is going to the same server as the main page
- as it's the same origin and destination, both are secure
- If I point a new browser window to the destination of the ajax call, the content returns the expected xml fine

This problem is inconsistent, like a race or timing problem, only when I initiate several requests in direct succession do I see the issue, and even then it's not always the same requests or number of requests that fail.  Sometimes, but rarely in my current test case, I'll see all calls return without issue.

Interestingly, I can't seem replicate this issue on my localhost just now, only when accessing our test, staging, or production servers.

Firefox isn't suffering from this problem, our user base is all IE though.

We are initiating these ajax calls manually/directly, rather than via jQuery.  I thought of trying jQuery, but it would involve a fair amount of updating my code, and wasn't sure that jQuery is doing anything more behind the scenes than just wrapping a XmlHttpRequest object in some handy parsers and handlers etc, if the problem is with the XmlHttpRequest object I don't see how that would help.

Another thought I had was to put a mandated delay between all ajax calls, but I'd hate to impose additional delay in our app.  I could also try making them synchronous but that would impose similar negative performance costs.

Comment: how many is "many"? there's a limit of 4-32 connections per server being batted around here (ie9 vs ff)

Comment: I'm kicking off around 15-20 requests in direct succession

Comment: Are you reusing the same `XMLHttpRequest` instance?

Comment: i would have some of the reqs wait for others, even if a serial pattern is not needed per se; it will help the app run soother more often in more places.